# Complex document - provide mapping for a few fields only but keep the rest as is

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

i have some pretty complex documents i want to store in elastic to retrieve them and make them searchable. I dont know the whole strucutre of the data, so i would like elastic to "swallow" everything as i put it in but define some indexed fields to make searching possible.

As soon as i provide a mapping for elastic i will get errors, if i dont define mappings i fear that the index will grow too big because elastic will index too much.

I create the index using php, but it boils down to this:

```
PUT localhost:9200/name-of-index

{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then - when i add one object to test everything i will get the following error:

status 400

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [name-of-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, 2187]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [name-of-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, 2187]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

The command i use to post the document is about:

```
POST localhost:9200/name-of-index/2187

{
    "title": "some title",
    "otherField": "other value",
    "obj": {
        "nestedProp": "nestedValue",
        "deepObj": {
            "someStorage": [
                ...
                {
                    "someVeryDeepProp": 1
                }
                ...                
            ]            
        }
    },
    "obj2": [
        "str1",
        "str2"
    ]
}
```

The node names are not real of course and the structure is much more complex than that. But i doubt that is the cause of my problem.

So how could i define a partial index and keep everything else as it is?

update: i forgot some elastic information..

```
{
  "name" : "KNJ_3Eg",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "4M9p8XiaQHKPz7N2AAuVlw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.6.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "a9861f4",
    "build_date" : "2019-01-24T11:27:09.439740Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that was just a stupid mistake, i forgot to add the type.

So the correct request to add a document should be:

```
POST localhost:9200/name-of-index/_doc/2187

{
    "title": "some title",
    "otherField": "other value",
    "obj": {
        "nestedProp": "nestedValue",
        "deepObj": {
            "someStorage": [
                ...
                {
                    "someVeryDeepProp": 1
                }
                ...                
            ]            
        }
    },
    "obj2": [
        "str1",
        "str2"
    ]
}
```

I guess from version 7 onwards it will be without "_doc" because types are generally deprecated.